Were there "remnants of surface-to-air missiles" found "south of Baghdad" after the April attack on Isfahan?
AP claims

Iraqis found what appeared to be remnants of surface-to-air missiles south of Baghdad. That, coupled with a suspected Israeli strike on a radar station in Syria the same day, suggests Israeli fighter jets flew over Syria into Iraq, then fired so-called “standoff missiles” into Iran for the Isfahan attack.

I'm quite skeptical those things happened like that. (Not that an attack took place.) What evidence is there for those "surface-to-air missiles south of Baghdad" aside from AP writing that? E.g. any photos? And were they (definitely) Iranian?
AFAICT, that's probably based on this story:

Baghdad - Al-Sharqiya, April 19: A security force found the remains of missiles that fell in the Al-Latifiya area, in the far south of Baghdad Governorate. Footage showed the teams concerned with removing explosives recovering an unexploded missile that had fallen on one of the Latifiya farms without causing any casualties, while specialists indicated that the missile was of the “Bombay air-to-surface” type, and that it had fallen into Iraqi territory due to confusion or loss of contact with it from Before the parties that launched it.

But where is Latifiya on a map?

If that's the one being talked about, that's pretty damn far from the Iranian border for Iranian SAMs to hit there. OTOH boosters from surface to surface missiles that Iran sometimes bombs the Kurds with would be expected to be found around there. (There's a booster shown in the picture attached to the last, Al-Sharqiya story. It's unclear though even if it's a generic photo or the one reportedly found on that day.)
Also "Bombay air-to-surface" (WTH does this even mean?) vs. "surface-to-air"? Same missile? An elephant?
3rd version of the story.

Farmers in Iraq today discovered fragments of the booster components of two Israeli missiles in the Latifiya and Al-Aziziya regions of Iraq, over 100 kilometers from the Iranian border. Military observers speculate these fragments likely belong to the “Blue Sparrow” Air-Launched Ballistic Missile (ALBM), developed by the Israeli defense company, Rafael.
Military observers speculate these fragments likely belong to the “Blue Sparrow” Air-Launched Ballistic Missile (ALBM), developed by the Israeli defense company, Rafael.

A photo caption in the last piece claims it's a "“Blue Sparrow” target missile".
So not Iranian (but Israeli) and not surface to air?

Yeah given the hard points seen in one of the photos, those were almost certainly aircraft attached weapons. I guess the remaining mystery is if Iran fired any surface-to-air missiles at the incoming, which might have also landed in Iraq.
